# Building Point Cloud Library (PCL) on macOS X Mojave error: ld: library not found for -lflann

Tags: c++, makefile, graphics, cmake, flann

I'm following a bunch of tutorials to install PCL... I'm getting the following error:

`ld: library not found for -lflann`

I installed `pcl` using `brew install pcl`. Here's my `CMakeList.txt`

```
set(PCL_DIR "/usr/local/Cellar/pcl/1.9.1/share/pcl-1.9/")

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR)

project(pcd_write)

set(PCL_DIR "/usr/local/Cellar/pcl/1.9.1/share/pcl-1.9/") 
find_package(PCL 1.9 REQUIRED)

include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

add_executable (pcd_write pcd_write.cpp)
target_link_libraries (pcd_write ${PCL_LIBRARIES})
```

cmake runs fine and creates the Makefile. When running make, I get:

```
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable pcd_write
ld: library not found for -lflann
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [pcd_write] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/pcd_write.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Is there an updated, definitive guide to install PCL on macOS Mojave? Thanks..!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem (when building pcl as part of ROS Kinetic on macOS Mojave). My workaround was opening `link.txt` in all the relevant subfolder of CMakeFiles and doing the following replacements:

1. Replacing `-lflann` by `/usr/local/lib/libflann.dylib`
2. Replacing `-lflann_cpp` by `/usr/local/lib/libflann_cpp.dylib`

Please note that these may occur several times in some files. As I use `catkin` for the entire build process, my location of these files will probably be slightly different from yours.

This solution is admittedly very hacky and I am sure there is a more proper way of doing this but it made the build work.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a shot. I ended up using Virtual Box to run an Ubuntu VM on my Mac and PCL installed without a hitch on Linux... I then built a thin web server to communicate between macOS and Linux... Hacky yes.. but I'll try your approach and report back.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the best way to solve this problem is to download pcl and compile it by yourself. Seems that pcl(1.9.1_4) from brew has wrong links to FLANN(1.9.1_7)

Anyway we can hack this... by modifying **FindFLANN.cmake** file in **'/usr/local/Cellar/pcl/1.9.1_4/share/pcl-1.9/Modules'**

At the beginning of the file, add:

```
set(FLANN_LIBRARIES /usr/local/Cellar/flann/1.9.1_7/lib/libflann.dylib /usr/local/Cellar/flann/1.9.1_7/lib/libflann_cpp.dylib)
set(FLANN_FOUND TRUE)
```

Hope this will help if you are fighting for building ROS on Mac :)

Answer (score 0):

I had built it successfully with following steps on [Mojave 10.14](https://www.apple.com/lae/macos/mojave/)

- step 1

```
brew install boost

brew install eigen

brew install flann

brew install vtk
```

- step 2

```sh
git clone https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl.git

mkdir BUILD

cd BUILD

cmake ..

make

sudo make install
```